# Android cordova push icon missing

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Recieving push notes works, yet the icon for my app remains empty

Tried the below and a path to one of the images in my asset folder. Neither works...

```
   let push = Push.init({
        android: {
          senderID: "XYZ",
          "icon": "drawable-ldpi-icon",
              "iconColor": "blue"
        },...
```

Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Are you using device for push notification or Genymotion ?

Comment: Are you using Android 5 ? It causes an issue where your icon gets a white mask, and if you have no transparency, you can get a white square only for your icon

Comment: Real phone with Android 6.0 . But the transparancy thing could be an issue. Do you have a link how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should crop your logo to white transparent png :

- platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_notify.png (24 × 24 )
- platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_notify.png (36 × 36)
- platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_notify.png (48 × 48)
- platforms/android/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_notify.png (72 × 72)
- platforms/android/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ic_notify.png (96 × 96)

or just go to [this link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=ac_unit&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_ac_unit)

to automaticly generate all format

put all four file on

```
\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_stat_ac_unit.png
\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_stat_ac_unit.png
\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_stat_ac_unit.png
\platforms\android\res\drawable-xxhdpi\ic_stat_ac_unit.png
\platforms\android\res\drawable-xxxhdpi\ic_stat_ac_unit.png
```

And make shourt that you specify

```
 Push.init({
         android: {
           senderID: "XYZ",
           "icon": "ic_stat_ac_unit",
               "iconColor": "blue"
         }....
```

In final case you will also specify

```
    var DATA = {
        "to": "fple.....",
        "data": {
              "title":"", // Title notification
              "message": "\u270C Peace, Love \u2764",
              "color":"#cccccc", // color title notification
              "icon":"ic_stat_ac_unit",
              "smallIcon": "ic_stat_ac_unit",
              "largeIcon": "ic_stat_ac_unit"
        }};
```